# How to display Button on form

Tags: c#, winforms

As in this picture, how I can create a list with users and display it on the `listbox` with two `buttons` delete and launch and when I can create there code what I must do help please !
[image: Users list]

Comment: Please provide code of what you have tried so far!

Comment: not specific enough, are we talking web, winforms or wcf? just the c# tag isnt sufficient

Comment: I did not try anything because this is the beginning I just want to know how to do it and i'm talking about windows form app.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to write windows forms application with C#. I use DataGridView for this purpose, because in datagridview we can define columns. The wireframe has 3 columns one is the name and others are launch and delete. There is also listview component if you like. If it is a webpage there are similar components like asp.net GridView. These components also have databindings with SqlDataSource, so CRUD operations can be done without coding.

[image: visual studio screenshot]

Comment: How to put two button for each user i can't understand explain please

Comment: I add screenshot to my answer. In the toolbox there is DataGridView. After adding this component, click on the small arrow on the top right. In the menu click edit columns and add DataGridViewButtonColumn

Comment: put how i can show the launch button not put it put show it when i add user show it in the data grid view with his two button how i can do this

Comment: when i click on delete this will delete it's user and so on .?

Comment: I cannot understand the situation well. My suggestion is in the upper textbox write a name and click add user. Then add the user to database. Rebind the datagridview so it can show the new user from database. The delete button is same, delete the user. Launch is different. Add new form to your project. Add a variable to hold the username. When launch button is clicked create instance of new form. set user variable and show the new form. Hope this can help because the question is not so clear.

Comment: i made a dynamic list for user when i show it on the listbox i need to show else two button for each user i displayed please that is Necessary for my project and i am from Egypt i can't speak English well

Comment: Then my suggestion is don't make 2 buttons for every user, make 2 buttons for the entire listbox. One launch button, when clicked check that any item in the listbox is selected. If selected make launch work with the selected item. If one item is selected make the same for delete button. Delete the selected user from the list when delete button is clicked.

Comment: put i didn't want to make one button for delete and launch i need to do as the picture as chat system ..... for each user two choice delete or launch are you understand me ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner to winforms, check this out.

[image: Screen]

Comment: No i mean appear two button for each user as it is in the picture for delete user or open new form  for chatting not put button like this